# How to make the output of server headers more readable?

Tags: php, arrays, readability

Given the following php5 code that output a gigantuous amount of *difficult to read* code:

```
<?=var_dump($_SERVER);?>
<?=print_r($GLOBALS); ?>
```

Question: how to make the output more human-readable? e.g. houw to but every "item" on a new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your development environment, you should install the [**Xdebug**](https://xdebug.org/) extension.

Amongst other useful features *(such as a debugger !)*, it'll get you nicer `var_dump()` :

- colors
- formating

For example, here's a screenshot of the beggining of the output I get for `var_dump($_SERVER);` :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-5604152.png))</sub>

Comment: +1 to this. Also the super helpful stacktrace the moment something goes wrong. Debugging is so easy!

Answer (score 5):

You can just wrap a pre-element around it:

```
<pre><?php var_dump($_SERVER); ?></pre>
<pre><?php print_r($GLOBALS); ?></pre>
```

Also note that `<?=` requires `short_open_tags` to be set to true (which is false in newer versions of php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<pre>` tag to format the output

```
<pre><?=print_r($GLOBALS); ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone else mentioned, you can wrap that in `<pre>` tags to make it readable. I usually have the following 2 functions in my code at all times. Used as utility functions, inspired by cake.

```
function pr() {
    $vars   = func_get_args();
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        print_r($var);
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}

function prd() { //dies after print
    $vars   = func_get_args();
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        print_r($var);
    }
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the `<pre>` trick, you can try using dbug

Makes things much nicer and clearer: [dBug](http://dbug.ospinto.com/)

Answer (score 1):

the previous answers suggest good solution, but if you want more control on the output you can run a loop over the arrays.

$_SERVER and $_GLOBALS are arrays, so you can do

```
foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value){
echo $key . ' is ' . $value . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

you can also add if statements to ignore some items in $_SERVER/$_GLOBALS

Comment: Not a really good idea, really. First, it's too much code compared to a simple "<pre>" tag. Second, it's no good for multidimensional arrays. Of course, you can put nested foreach loops, but how far are you willing to go for something that can be done better using <pre>? And if you are going to make it pretty, you really should consider using dbug

Comment: it's great idea if you want something simple, portable and more pretty then <pre>/var_dump() without using debug. this particular example wont work for multi-dimensional arrays, but $_SERVER is one-dimensional and with little edits it can also support multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: More simple, portable and pretty than <pre>? Surely you jest. If you need a quick look in the array, nothing is easier than <pre>. If you are going to make things pretty, use a library like dBug. If you need a closer look, xdebug is it (but a pain to install/configure). There is no case where writing your own loops is easier. Not to mention that it looks like regular code, and you will occasionally forget why it's there.  Fast & clean, pre. Pretty, dBug. Detailled, xdebug. Unduly complicated, write your own dodgy version of dBug every time. There, it fits a niche.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not whatever "server headers" but regular arrays.
2. To output array contents, a programmer usually makes use of **a loop**, and then format output in the manner they wish:

.

```
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
  echo "<b>$key:</b> $value<br>\n";
}
```

Note that your output being gigantic only because you're printing out the contents of $GLOBALS variable, which being completely useless for you.

Comment: Not a good idea for debugging purposes. See comments to Gilsilas' answer.

Comment: @Sylverdrag it's good enough for his current task. In fact, he's getting a mess with multidimensional arrays which he don't need at all.